# Remix Solidity Smart Contract Stuck On Compiling State

Tags: solidity, remix, compilation, compiler, solidity-0.7.x

The *[1inch Smart Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302#code)* is unable to compile in Remix as it appears to be stuck in the Solidity compiling phase.

## Expected

1. Create a new *1inch_38211317.sol* smart contract file in Remix.
2. Compile the contract.
3. Deploy and run the contract on the Ropsten Test Network.

## Observed

1. The 1inch Smart Contract code is copied into a new *1inch_Test.sol* file.
2. The default compiler version throws an error.

> browswer/1inch_38211317.sol:782:1: ParseError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.4+commit.3f05b770.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version pragma solidity ^0.6.0

[image: Compiler error]

3. Change the compiler to the *latest local version - 0.7.4*
4. The *Compile 1inch_38211317.sol* button is stuck in the compiling/loading state.

[image: Compile stuck]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of an awkward one.

`0.7.4` is too high, given some of the contracts<sup>†</sup> are `^0.6.0` (and [the `^` prevents using `0.7.x`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/layout-of-source-files.html#pragmas).)

But you'll need at least `0.6.5` due to the use of the [`immutable`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82240/what-is-the-immutable-keyword-in-solidity) keyword in one of the contracts.

So really your choices are >=`0.6.5` but < `0.7.0`. (I've checked they work.)

(  <sup>†</sup> The important point here being that there are multiple contracts in the that one file.)