# Is the gas cost for constant and immutable about equal?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, constant, immutable

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54101635/10261711) the Solidity 0.5.0 Compiler cannot compute a `constant` state variable that invokes a function, however I'm also experiencing this issue on Solidity 0.8.10 using the [ABDKMath64x64 library](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import { ABDKMath64x64 } from "./ABDKMath64x64.sol";

contract FixedPoint {
    // TypeError Initial value for constant variable has to be compile-time constant
    int128 constant someFixedPointInteger = ABDKMath64x64.fromUInt(123);
}
```

So I instead opted to use `immutable` by initialising the state variable in the `constructor` as follows:

```
contract FixedPoint {
    int128 immutable someFixedPointInteger;

    constructor() {
        someFixedPointInteger = ABDKMath64x64.fromUInt(123);
    }
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101823/10261711):

> `constant`s aren't stored in storage anywhere; they're substituted in the bytecode

This obviously entails gas savings since no `SLOAD` is executed to retrieve `constant`s from storage, since they're interpolated directly into the bytecode. Can the same be said about `immutable` variables that will result in similar gas savings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the case. This has also been outlined here [What is the immutable keyword in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82240/what-is-the-immutable-keyword-in-solidity) and can be found in the official Solidity docs here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables